# Channel form : Ajax submisson

Tags: safecracker, channel, ajax

It's the first time I've used Ajax with Channel Form so this maybe a newbie question.

I'm loading the template containing my form via AJAX and appending it to a DIV. When the form is submitted I want to show messaging in the same DIV so I'm overriding the default form submit in jQuery but I can't prevent the page from refreshing. If I set the form parameter ajax="yes" then it simply redirects to JSON output.

What am I missing?

Static form ID works fine:

```
<form id="comment-form">
          <input type="text">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Channel Form ID does not work:

```
{exp:channel:form 
          channel="logbook"
          include_jquery="no"
          include_assets="no"
          datepicker="no"
          class="logbook-add"
          id="comment-form"
          return="/account/manage-logbook-requests/#comments"
          entry_id="{segment_3}"
        }
```

jQuery code:

```
$("#comment-form").on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('submitted');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

`json="yes"` parameter is merely changing format of data output. You will need to add appropriate Javascript code to handle submission and displaying of results.

See [example in the docs](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/channel/channel_form/examples.html#ajax-driven-entry-form). You can use it as the base but change code that is producing alert to code that will show success/error message in same div (e.g. using jQuery's `.html()` function)

Comment: Hi Yuri, thanks for your comment. The bizarre thing is I have a jQuery event handler preventing the form from submitting but it is not working. If I create a static form with the same ID it does work, but it does not work for the same ID on the Channel Form. I will update my original post with the code.

Comment: You might be getting some javascript conflict. Check you browser console for errors.

Comment: I think the parameter should be json="yes" not ajax="yes"

Comment: @mjr, you're right